# foreign key laravel migration

Tags: laravel, database-migration

This is my `students` migration and I want to have foreign key in it named `subject_id`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('student_code');
        $table->string('national_code');
        $table->integer('subject_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('subject_id')
            ->references('id')->on('subjects');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and this is my `subjects` migation:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My problem is very simple I searched in document and found nothing except my migration codes. I am confused.
anyway first of all I ran `subjects` migration script then `students` but I get strange error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table students add constraint students_subject_id_foreign foreign key (subject_id) references subjects (id))
```

Comment: What's the order of your migrations? `subjects` first or `students` first?

Comment: Anyway, `subjects` should be first

Comment: @Tarasovych subjects is first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is in `subject_id` definition.
Local and foreign key must be same type, in our case:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('subject_id');
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html:

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

So, your `subjects` table `id` has `BIG INT` datatype,`subject_id` should have the same data type.

Use `$table->unsignedBigInteger('subject_id');` instead.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=4095):

> a foreign key column must have the same data type + the same length +
>   the same scale as the corresponding referenced column

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your fields defining order. You have to add all your fields first then add foreign keys.

Try below code:-

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('student_code');
        $table->string('national_code');
        $table->integer('subject_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('subject_id')
            ->references('id')->on('subjects');
    });
}
```